# Why html file rendered from a local storage does not send a request to a server?

Tags: html, forms, url, browser

I am inspecting a webpage, which apart from other content has the following `form` containing a **Submit** button:

```
<form action="/process" method="post">
        <p><input type="submit" value="Submit"></p>
</form>
```

When I click the **Submit** button, the website successfully processes my `post` request and sends a response.

I saved the source html of this page to a local file on my computer, then I opened the local file with a browser. The browser displays the webpage just like the original one.

However, when I click the **Submit** button, I get an error:

```
Your file couldn’t be accessed
It may have been moved, edited, or deleted.
ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
```

the reason, ASAIK, is that the browser searches for a `/process` file on my computer and does not find one.

**QUESTION**: Why does the browser search for this file on my local computer, rather than sending a request to a remote server?

Answer (score 1):

The `action` attribute requires a URL for where to send the data. `/process` is directing the browser to send the data to your local computer because that is where the form came from. It's relative to where the form is served from.

To correct this, obviously and as you surmised, is to supply a proper URL that points to your online server.